# Android ID as an alternative to Device ID

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, runtime-permissions

My apps have always used DeviceId as a unique identifier and this, of course, requires READ_PHONE_STATE as a permission.  That has been ok in the past but now I have migrated to Marshmellow 23 where asking for this permission displays a very scary dialog at run time saying...

"Allow {my app} to make and manage phone calls?"

That's a pretty hideous message for an app that just wants to get deviceId.

I'm thinking of switching over to Android ID as it doesn't require any permission.

```
String androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Googling around I see there have been some problems using android ID but it's all old stuff.  Back in Froyo days there was a phone vendor that produced the same ID for all of their phones but that's about all I have seen.

Is anyone aware of any problems using Android ID?
Thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What unique identifier you choose to use depends heavily on what specific use case you need the identifier for. The [Best Practices for Unique Identifiers training](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html) goes through many common use cases and which identifier to use. They do have a number of tenents of working with Android Identifiers:

> 1: **Avoid using hardware identifiers.** **Hardware identifiers such as SSAID (Android ID) and IMEI can be avoided in most use-cases** without limiting required functionality.
>
> 2: *Only use Advertising ID for user profiling or ads use-cases.* When using an Advertising ID, always respect the Limit Ad Tracking flag, ensure the identifier cannot be connected to personally identifiable information (PII) and avoid bridging Advertising ID resets.
>
> 3: **Use an Instance ID or a privately stored GUID whenever possible for all other use-cases except payment fraud prevention and telephony.** For the vast majority of non-ads use-cases, an instance ID or GUID should be sufficient.
>
> 4: *Use APIs that are appropriate to your use-case to minimize privacy risk.* Use the DRM API API for high value content protection and the SafetyNet API for abuse prevention. The Safetynet API is the easiest way to determine whether a device is genuine without incurring privacy risk.

In the vast majority of cases, Android ID is still not the right thing to use.

Comment: I think IMEI is the only thing to prevent users for re-installing trial software but in my case a UUID will do the trick.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I have one doubt , please help me on that, How to get the unique ID of the user which can not change even wipe out data from the device, I heard about the "Advertisement ID", is it solve my problem, Please help me on it. Thanks